# Comparing nil properties in isEqual

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, equality, nsnumber

**EDIT**

From the initial answers, I wasn't clear enough. I just want to check equality between objects of my own custom class, with the result dependent on its properties (pretty standard I believe)? The bit I'm struggling with is making sure a property is treated as equal when both instances have nil for that property.

**END EDIT**

I want objects of my custom class to return `YES` for `isEqual` whenever all of its properties are the same as those of the object passed as the argument. This should include when both **properties** are `nil`. I recently learned that `[nil isEqual:nil]` returns `NO`.

Will the below implementation achieve what I am looking for?

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
    {
       if (object == self)
            return YES;
        if (!object || ![object isKindOfClass:[self class]])
            return NO;

        return (
            (!object.numberProperty && !self.numberProperty) || (object.numberProperty && self.numberProperty && [object.numberProperty isEqualToNumber:self.numberProperty])
            &&
            (!object.stringProperty && !self.stringProperty) || object.stringProperty && self.stringProperty && [object.stringProperty isEqualToNumber:self.stringProperty])
        ...etc
        );
    }
```

I am trying to return `YES` when both properties are `nil` and also avoid sending `isEqualToNumber` or `isEqualToString` to nil.

For `BOOL`s I would guess that this is not necessary since a `BOOL` can't be `nil` - will a simple `==` suffice for booleans?

Anything I'm missing, or any ways to improve this?

Comment: So do you want a method that returns `YES` when called like `[nil someEqualityTest:nil]`? -- Apart from that, yes, `BOOL` is a primitive type, `==` works as expected.

Comment: The problem would be to get `[nil isEqual:nil]` to even call your `isEqual`.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to check [myObject isEqual:myObject], and return YES when all properties match. I want both properties being nil to be a 'match'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can't (ok, it's just not a good idea) override isEquals for all object types including `nil`, the obvious choice is to just make a separate simple function for the times you need it;

```objc
BOOL nilEqual(id a, id b)
{
    return (a == nil && b == nil) || [a isEqual:b];
}
```

Comment: So then if a is nil and b is not nil, I will be executing [nil isEqual:b] - is that ok? And likewise for [a isEqual:nil]? I suppose in each case I will get NO as intended?

Comment: @BenPackard It is ok, since [isEqual](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:) on NSObject is documented to allow `nil`.

Comment: Thanks. Final question - does isEqual always just call the equivalent isEqualTo*? I would prefer to use isEqualToDate, isEqualToString (I just like the clarity of that). But I will use isEqual like you suggest if it will do the appropriate thing depending on the receivier's class.

Comment: @BenPackard The only difference is what Apple says in the documentation of most `isEqualTo...` methods as in NSString.isEqualToString; `Special Considerations:
When you know both objects are strings, this method is a faster way to check equality than isEqual:.` Seems to be [very small difference though](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/334-isequal-vs-isequaltostring/).

Comment: Thanks. The (50%) type checking is nice though.

Comment: If both `a` and `b` are `nil`, then `a==b` is true (`YES`).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found a little bit simpler and more optimized solution than https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033891/440168:

```
BOOL nilEqual(id a, id b)
{
    return (a == b) || [a isEqual:b];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nil` cannot call `isEqual` since it is... well nil. It would not know which `isEqual` to call. It is not an object. I do not know of a way to do this and doubt there is away (someone please correct me, I would love to see an implementation for this).

That being said, normally you need to check for nil pointers **before** calling `isEqual` so:

```
if ((!someObject && !otherObject) || [someObject isEqual:otherObject]);
```

This would give you what you want and you could easily create a block (or maybe a macro) so you would not have to type out this out every time.

Comment: I'm trying to compare the properties of the object, not the objects themselves.

Comment: That's inaccurate. An answer is more than the just the code it includes. The accepted answer did a better job explaining how and where this would be used, at least according to the asker (and based on the sunsequent upvotes).

Comment: @BenPackard I think they were mostly referring to the lack of understanding you expressed in your first comment. It seems to elude that you suspect the answer is incorrect, even though the accepted solution is functionally equivalent. As the asker, you have the full right to accept the solution you feel is best.

Comment: I think there is definitely a lack of understanding in my first comment. I also think there is a subtle difference in the answers that partially accounts for that. It was a couple of years ago now, of course, but I think it was about my  understanding that this could be added to the object as a method, which is most similar to how I wanted to be able to compare objects, rather than your (equally functional) suggestion. Anyway, enough meta-SO I guess. If nothing else, it's too painful to read back your own questions so long after the fact :/